# Installing Zend on CentOS is having dependency issues

Tags: php, centos, dependencies, zend

I'm trying to install PHP's Zend Server on my CentOS VPS but it's having dependency issues that I can't seem to resolve.

```
zend-server-php-5.2-4.0-73.noarch from Zend_noarch has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php-5.2-gui-zend-server is needed by package zend-server-php-5.2-4.0-73.noarch (Zend_noarch)
zend-server-php-5.2-4.0-73.noarch from Zend_noarch has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php-5.2-dev-zend-server is needed by package zend-server-php-5.2-4.0-73.noarch (Zend_noarch)
knowledgetree-ce-3.7.0-2.noarch from KTnoarch has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php-5.2-xmlrpc-zend-server is needed by package knowledgetree-ce-3.7.0-2.noarch (KTnoarch)
knowledgetree-ce-3.7.0-2.noarch from KTnoarch has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php-5.2-fileinfo-zend-server is needed by package knowledgetree-ce-3.7.0-2.noarch (KTnoarch)
zend-server-php-5.2-4.0-73.noarch from Zend_noarch has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php-5.2-zend-extensions is needed by package zend-server-php-5.2-4.0-73.noarch (Zend_noarch)
zend-server-php-5.2-4.0-73.noarch from Zend_noarch has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php-5.2-common-extensions-zend-server is needed by package zend-server-php-5.2-4.0-73.noarch (Zend_noarch)
Error: Missing Dependency: php-5.2-fileinfo-zend-server is needed by package knowledgetree-ce-3.7.0-2.noarch (KTnoarch)
Error: Missing Dependency: php-5.2-xmlrpc-zend-server is needed by package knowledgetree-ce-3.7.0-2.noarch (KTnoarch)
Error: Missing Dependency: php-5.2-gui-zend-server is needed by package zend-server-php-5.2-4.0-73.noarch (Zend_noarch)
Error: Missing Dependency: php-5.2-common-extensions-zend-server is needed by package zend-server-php-5.2-4.0-73.noarch (Zend_noarch)
Error: Missing Dependency: php-5.2-dev-zend-server is needed by package zend-server-php-5.2-4.0-73.noarch (Zend_noarch)
Error: Missing Dependency: php-5.2-zend-extensions is needed by package zend-server-php-5.2-4.0-73.noarch (Zend_noarch)
```

When consulting the Google, all I get told is how to install PHP 5.2.* on CentOS. According to the output of `php -v`, I've done that.

```
PHP 5.2.8 (cli) (built: Sep 28 2009 15:37:15)
Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2008 Zend Technologies with the ionCube PHP Loader v3.1.34, Copyright (c) 2002-2009, by ionCube Ltd.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can grab all of the dependencies from zend's [repository](http://repos.zend.com/zend-server/rpm/noarch/).

Comment: I have the Zend repo added to my YUM repo.d folder. It still doesn't resolve the dependencies. Performing a `yum search [package]` also returns no results. My Zend Repo file is here http://codepad.org/oGALx5Em

Comment: Try downloading them from the link and using `rpm -i` ?

Comment: Which package version should I download? No version is specified in the YUM output, so should I just grab the latest version? For example, `php-5.2-common-extensions-zend-server-4.0-19.noarch.rpm` ?

Comment: Try the latest, yes.

Comment: That just gave me a nice big list of other dependencies I'm going to have to install by hand >.< There's gotta be a reason why the /etc/yum.repo.d/zend.repo file isn't working... I'd rather not do this manually.

Comment: Try running `yum clean all`.

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. I managed to install Zend by using their installer (http://www.zend.com/products/server-ce/downloads) but I still can't get the required dependencies (listed above) to install. Is there a way to confirm the repo.d repo is working? It seems strange that it can't find files, that obviously exist, from a repo it's being linked to :/

Comment: It they don't show up in `yum list` then it is a problem with the repository configuration.

Comment: It seems those packages aren't showing up `yum list`... They're in the repository you linked to, though, which is what my repo.d file links to. So what's up with that? :/